# Display all filters in layered navigation after applying any filter in magento1

Tags: layered-navigation, magento1.9.3

I have to Display all filters in layered navigation after applying any filter on it.

The filter shouldn't change according to product resultset on the category page.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this functionality in Magento 1.9 and aw_layerednavigation 1.5.0.community_edition?

Comment: For Magento 2, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I just found one module from GitHub maybe it helps you, you can figure it out your issue by installing this module 
https://github.com/caciobanu/improved-magento-layered-navigation

If the above module does not work for you, try this one https://github.com/karliuka/m1.MultiLayer

Let me know if both not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am working on aw_layerednavigation-1.5.0.community_edition can't change this extension I have to achieve the functionality with same extension. If you can share the code or method for filter display than it would be great help. Thanks in advance!